# unable to get system variable HTTP_AUTHORIZATION in PHP application running under IIS

Tags: php, iis, authorization

I send a GET request from a site hosted on a domain to a PHP application hosted on another domain under Windows 2019.

I get rid off the CORS issues and the PHP application receives and processes the GET request.

However, I am not able to get the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION variable, it is empty, although it is set in the GET request as:

```
authorization: Bearer sampleJwtToken
```

I have googled a lot and see there are some issues and fixes for this under Apache, but I can't find any fix for IIS, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP authentication in PHP only works when PHP is running as an Apache module, so this feature does not work with the CGI version.

> In order to get HTTP Authentication to work using IIS server with the
> CGI version of PHP you must edit your IIS configuration "Directory
> Security". Click on "Edit" and only check "Anonymous Access", all
> other fields should be left unchecked.
>
> **IIS Note:**
>
> For HTTP Authentication to work with IIS, the PHP directive
> cgi.rfc2616_headers must be set to 0 (the default value).

If security mode is enabled, the script's UID will be added to the realm part of the WWW-Authenticate header.

For more information, please refer to the related [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) of PHP.